# Trying to split Mongoose models out into sud documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm sure this is a syntax issue somewhere along the way. I've got a Mongoose model where part of it looks like this:

```
SMS_Data: {
        _id: false,
        SMS_User: [{
            Username: {
                type: String
            },
            Password: {
                type: String
            }
        }]
    }
```

This works fine, but I'm trying to split things out into subdocuments. So I've created a SMS_User.js model that looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const sms_user = mongoose.Schema({
    SMS_User: {
        Username: {
            type: String
        },
        Password: {
            type: String
        }
    }
})

module.exports = sms_user;
```

I require it into the main model using:
`const sms_user = require('./SMS_User');`

And tried changing the main model to now read like this:

```
SMS_Data: {
        _id: false,
        SMS_User: [sms_user]
    }
```

But this doesn't work. Instead of selecting the user I expected, based on the Username and Password. But when I use this from my login controller:

```
const user = await my_model.findOne({ 'SMS_Data.SMS_User.Username': userId, 'SMS_Data.SMS_User.Password': userPw });
```

it just selects the first record in the collection, instead of the correct one when I use the un-nested version of the model. Which suggest to me that the nesting of the sub model is wrong.

Like I say this could be glaringly obvious, but I'm just not seeing where I'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "_it just selects_" - what is `it` here?

Comment: Sorry. I mean if I try to use the model to select a record. I'll amend my question.

Comment: did you log schema after changing to see what it looks like. you will see a paths field

Comment: Can I just ask how you would do that: console.log(my_model) returns a load of data, a lot of which I suspect is unnecessary.

Comment: yeah it outputs a lot but it also gives the structure but not very readable. you will see fields named path with values like `SMS_Data.SMS_User.Username`. idk if there is better  way to viualize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way you have broken down the schema is wrong since you have added an extra level of nesting (i.e `'SMS_Data.SMS_User.SMS_User.Username'` etc).

You need to remove the `SMS_User` from `sms_user` schema

```js
  const sms_user = mongoose.Schema({
    Username: {
      type: String
    },
    Password: {
      type: String
    }
  })

  const parentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    //other fields
    SMS_Data: {
      _id: false,
      SMS_User: [sms_user]
    }
  })
```

Comment: Thanks dude. As I said "could be glaringly obvious", and it was. Thanks for your help.